# hyperref and underscores

Tags: hyperref

hyperref seems not to work with `\_` in the first argument of either `hypertarget` or `hyperlink`:

```
 \hypertarget{foo\_}{foo\_}
 \hyperlink{foo\_}{foo\_}
```

When clicking on the hyperlink it always jumps to the beginning of the document. I get the correct behavior by removing `\_` or, for example, writing

```
 \hypertarget{foo_}{foo\_}
 \hyperlink{foo_}{foo\_}
```

The problem is that the two functions are used as a part of custom commands which require both arguments to be the same.

```
\newcommand{\mytarget}[1]{\hypertarget{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{#1}}
```

I tried removing the underscore in the first argument with

```
\newcommand{\mytarget}[1]{\hypertarget{\StrSubstitute{#1}{\_}{dummy}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{\hyperlink\StrSubstitute{#1}{\_}{dummy}}{#1}}
```

but it gives me a compilation error. Is it possible to renew the two hyperref commands so that some characters are replaced in the first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do the substitution beforehand:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\makesub}[1]{%
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{\_}{_}[\temp]%
  \restoreexpandmode
}
\newcommand{\mytarget}[1]{%
  \makesub{#1}%
  \hypertarget{\temp}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{%
  \makesub{#1}%
  \hyperlink{\temp}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\mytarget{foo\_bar}
\lipsum

\mylink{foo\_bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what is the function of `saveexpandmode` and `noexpandarg`? I'm not sure if they're required for my text. The relevant words only have the form `foo1\_foo2\_...`.

Comment: @RaulLaasner They're not so important if that's the only application of `xstring` in your document: in that case just `\noexpandarg` in the preamble is sufficient. Read in the manual about `\fullexpandarg` and friends.

Comment: @egreg It seems to me like this is an inconsistency in `hyperref` (hypertarget supports PDF Standard characters and does not expand while hyperlink fully expands?). I would classify this inconsistency as a bug. Maybe I am wrong. Could you explain the reasoning for this?

Comment: @macmadness86 Underscores *are* supported in the second argument of `\hyperref`; it's the OP who wants to use just one argument both for typesetting and the link.

Comment: @egreg My issue is with expansion of tokens in arg1. If you have arg1 in both `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` set to `foo\_`, then I would expect the link to work. `hyperref` should interpret the target as 5 chars AND the link as 5 chars. What I see happening is the total chars for target=5 and total chars for link=4 (because `\_` in link gets interpreted as one char, but as two chars in the target).

Comment: @macmadness86 Sorry, I don't get it; actually the link name is argument 1 in `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`, where `_` is legal. There's no apparent reason that the two arguments should be the same: the first is just a label.

Comment: of course the two args must be the same if you expect the link to find the target. i will open a question with details. "just labels" is the best haha. they make or break the association between ref and target and should be unique. Better is to say arg2 is "just a caption". That has no special uniqueness criterion.